# Is is possible to insert an image into an excel cell via COM?

Tags: excel, com, image, automation

I have used automation to insert values into a cell, however I have never seen any documentation, for example, that demonstrate inserting anything other than text and/or formula's.

Has anybody been able to insert an image from an external application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Dim FileName as string
FileName="c:\text.jpg"
Set NewPic = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(FileName)
NewPic.top=100
NewPic.left=100
```

If you want to position the picture to a specific cell then select that cell as a range and use that ranges top/left/with to position the picture.

Samples: http://exceltip.com/st/Insert_pictures_using_VBA_in_Microsoft_Excel/486.html

**Note**: In Excel cells cannot contain pictures. The pictures live on an invisible drawing layer that floats about the cells. They can be positioned based on the cell coordinates, which makes it feel like they are living "in" the cells.

Comment: In Excel 2010, the Pictures.Insert function has been silently changed. The image inserted this way becomes "live" link to the file. So, to create static images on the sheet, you now should use Shapes.AddPicture(fileName, false, true, ...) as mentioned below.

Answer (score 3):

I see it's already been answered, but see my post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/688485/how-can-i-find-out-about-undocumented-net-com-library-functions).

Basically rather than use the Worksheet.Pictures.Insert method (which the MSDN recommends you don't use directly, and which returns a raw COM object), try the Worksheet.Shapes.AddPicture method instead.

```
Dim range As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range
Dim pic as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Shape
Dim filePath as String

range = ...
filePath = ...
pic = range.Worksheet.Shapes.AddPicture(filePath, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoCTrue, range.Left, range.Top, 300, 300)
```

It's not quite as straightforward because you have to specify the exact position and dimensions, but otherwise, pretty cool!

Answer (score 2):

Sure, the following code gives a good example using the Microsoft Interop libraries:

```
   string excelfilename = @"C:\excelfile.xlsx";
   string picturename = @"C:\image.jpg";

    object missing = Type.Missing;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application app = new ApplicationClass();
    Workbook book =  app.Workbooks.Add(missing);
    Worksheet sheet = (Worksheet)book.ActiveSheet;
    Pictures pics = (Pictures)sheet.Pictures(missing);
    pics.Insert(picturename, missing);
    book.SaveAs(excelfilename, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange,
        missing, missing, missing, missing, missing);
    app.Quit();
    app = null;
```