# Inserting Image in Excel from String

Tags: c#, image, excel

I'm generating a CSV file from the following code

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var csv = "मानक हिन्दी;some other value";
    var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(csv);
    data = Encoding.UTF8.GetPreamble().Concat(data).ToArray();
    var cd = new ContentDisposition
    {
        Inline = false,
        FileName = "newExcelSheet.csv"
    };
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", cd.ToString());
    return File(data, "text/csv");
}
```

Now I wish to insert Image in the top row of the excel, Please assist me in the following problem

Thanks :)

Comment: You can Encode the Bitmap Object int Base64String and get back the String from Base64String.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSV is not a format capable of including binary data such as images. The only thing you can include in a CSV file **is text**.

If you need to add an image to an excel document you would have to use a proper excel file (i.e. a `.xls` or `.xlsx` file). There are various APIs that you can use to write to such files, including the [Excel Object Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wss56bz7.aspx) exposed through COM when you have Office installed.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/521979/is-is-possible-to-insert-an-image-into-an-excel-cell-via-com) for details on how to insert images through COM.

Comment: Interop is NOT supported in ASP.NET !

Comment: Thanks.. That was of great help

Comment: Yahia :o


I use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel in ASP.NET with C#

Comment: @Sirwani MS says it is NOT supported - see http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;q257757#kb2

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it without using the interop assembly. You either go that route or download epplus, a free Excel .Net library that supports what you need.

Code examples on the website:

http://epplus.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

CSV doesn't support what you ask for AND **[Interop is officially NOT supported by MS in server-scenarios (like ASP.NET...)](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;q257757#kb2)**.

You will need to create "real" Excel files (XLS or XLSX) - some options to create Excel files:

MS provides the free OpenXML SDK V 2.0 - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb448854%28office.14%29.aspx

This can read+write MS Office files (including Excel XLSX but not XLS!).

Another option see http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/OpenXML.aspx

IF you need more like rendering, formulas etc. then there are different free and commercial libraries like [ClosedXML](http://closedxml.codeplex.com/), [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/), [Aspose.Cells](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.cells-for-.net/default.aspx), [SpreadsheetGear](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/), [LibXL](http://www.libxl.com/) and [Flexcel](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/flexcelnet.asp).